# how many SSL certificate can be listed in SSLServercert?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, mod-ssl

I wanted to list more than one certificate in SSLServercert, so that websites can use either one of these certificates. i will use "SSLServercert label1 label2" in httpd.conf file. label1 has IP based ceritifacate and lable2 has domain based certificate. if users make website calls with IP or with doamin name, either one of the certificate should work. is this possible?

Comment: What web server? As far as I can tell `SSLServerCert` is from `mod_ibm_ssl`?

Comment: If you were mistaken that having more than one SSL certificate on your website would enhance its security, I'd be concerned where you got that from.

Answer (score 2):

No - the website can't "choose" which certificate to use.  Only you can.

With SNI, you can configure name-based virtual hosts to have a different certificate per host header on the same listener, which is probably what you want - configure a virtual host for the hostname listener with the hostname cert, and an IP virtual host with the IP cert (and otherwise identical configuration).